# Page-break-after:always is being ignored by the browsers

Tags: html, css

I am mailing a HTML page as attachment.

I have used `<div style="page-break-after:always;>  </div>` 2 times here and there.

It is supposed to be 3 pages, but the browser ignores the page breaks and removes all the empty space of the page and it's giving 2 pages after printing.

The code is working fine with ThunderBird, the problem is with browsers.

How do I enforce this page break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to display page breaks on a browser. As far as I know, browsers don't support [paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/), and therefore ignore that kind of elements (including carriage returns).

In a print preview, for instance, pagination should be displaying correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Page breaks were introduced in CSS2 as a way of managing printed content, not content for the screen.  This style tells your browser how to send web content to the printer.  Browsers don't auto-paginate.

**Edited for redundancy**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to raise a dead thread - but I found this during a search

Did you use

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;> </div>
```

exactly?

if so try putting in the closing "

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;"> </div>
```

as of now (may 2013) page-break-after:always; is supported well  - but IE 10 does have some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Support for [`page-break-after`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-after) is limited.